# Cross compiling py-spidev for arm

Tags: python, arm, cross-compiling

I'm trying to cross-compile py-spidev module for an ARM9 (embedded system).

In an Ubuntu 64-bit VM, I did this(in my home directory):

```
git clone https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev
cd py-spidev
export PATH=$PATH:"Path_to_my_cross_compiler"
export ARCH=arm
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-none-linux-gnueabi-
python setup.py install --prefix=~/
```

But spidev_module.c is compiled with x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc and not my cross-compiler (arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-gcc).

How can I force python setup.py install to use my cross compiler?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution, so I post it for those who have the same problem.

This is what I did :

```
git clone https://github.com/doceme/py-spidev
cd py-spidev
export ARCH=arm
PLAT=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-
export CROSS_COMPILE=arm-poky-linux-gnueabi-
export PATH=$PATH:"Path_to_my_cross_compiler"
export CC="${PLAT}gcc -pthread"
export LDSHARED="${CC} -shared"
export CROSSBASE="Path of destination"
export CFLAGS="-I "path to python cross compiled include" -I${CROSSBASE}/usr/include"
export LDFLAGS="-L "path to python cross compiled libs" -L${CROSSBASE}/lib -L${CROSSBASE}/usr/lib"
python setup.py install --prefix=CROSSBASE
```

Enjoy :)

Comment: +1. Helpful not just for py-spidev, but also for other packages. Tip: some of those flags are automatically set when you `source` the poky toolchain, as mentioned here: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/sdk-manual/sdk-manual.html#sdk-running-the-sdk-environment-setup-script. The problem for me was that `LDSHARED` was not auto-set, so during *setup.py install*, it still uses the x86_64 for linking the .so file. I had to manually set `LDSHARED` to fix the problem.